# R: Best way to convert a mts to a non-time series dataframe with time indexes

Tags: datetime, r, data-structures, time-series

I'm currently using the following method to convert a mts dataset to a data frame with time indexes as columns.  Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
z <- ts(matrix(rnorm(300), 100, 3), start=c(1961, 1), frequency=12)
YM<-cbind(Year=as.numeric(floor(time(z))),Month=as.numeric(cycle(z)))
z<-cbind(as.data.frame(YM),as.data.frame(z))

str(z)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
data.frame(Year = c(floor(time(z) + .01)), Month = c(cycle(z)), z)
```

or

```
as.data.frame(cbind(Year = floor(time(z) + .01), Month = cycle(z), z))
```

Comment: This solution works great, except a few cases where it yielded a very vexing bug.  I suggest using the following function to make absolutley sure year is being calculated correctly.                        `as.data.frame(cbind(Year = trunc(round(time(z),1))), Month = cycle(z), z))`

Comment: In that case add a small number to avoid floating point problems.  I have edited the solution to show that.

Answer (score 4):

You can extract the index from the ts with `index()` (from zoo package)

```
zindex <- index(z)
zdf <- data.frame(Year = trunc(zindex), Month = (zindex - trunc(zindex)) * 12, z)
```

Or generate a sequence of dates with

```
Year = rep(1961:1969, each = 12)[1:100]
Month = rep(1:12, times = 9)[1:100]
```

Comment: I thought there was a function to do `x - trunc(x)` but I'm drawing a blank at the moment...

Comment: `index()` is not a base function, so you should specify that it's in the zoo package.

Comment: Whats the difference between index() in zoo and time() in base?

Comment: @Zach: Good question.  `time` is in base and there is a `zoo::time`, which simply calls `index`.

Answer (score 2):

A similar solution to @jonw's, but using xts:

```
x <- as.xts(z)
d <- data.frame(Year=.indexyear(x)+1900, Month=.indexmon(x)+1, coredata(x))
```